# Why "font-not-found" when complied by xelatex?

Tags: fonts

I met a problem. I downloaded a CV template from a scholar and complied it using xelatex. His code is attached as below,

```
% Jason R. Blevins - Curriculum Vitae
%
% Copyright (C) 2004-2017 Jason R. Blevins <jrblevin@sdf.org>
% http://jblevins.org/
%
% You may use use this document as a template to create your own CV
% and you may redistribute the source code freely.  No attribution is
% required in any resulting documents.  I do ask that you please leave
% this notice and the above URL in the source code if you choose to
% redistribute this file.

\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

% Set your name here
\def\name{Jason R. Blevins}

% Load packages
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Enumerate with [resume] option
\usepackage{fontspec} % Requires XeTeX
\usepackage{sectsty} % Custom section fonts

% Body
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}

% Title
\newfontfamily\titleface{Chaparral Pro Subhead}
\newcommand{\titlefont}[1]{{\titleface\large\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

% Section Headings
\newfontfamily\sectionface{Chaparral Pro Subhead}
\sectionfont{\sectionface\mdseries\normalsize\uppercase}
\subsectionfont{\sectionface\mdseries\normalsize\itshape}

% Other possible font commands include:
% \ttfamily for teletype,
% \sffamily for sans serif,
% \bfseries for bold,
% \scshape for small caps,
% \normalsize, \large, \Large, \LARGE sizes.

% The following metadata will show up in the PDF properties
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks = true,
  urlcolor = black,
  pdfauthor = {\name},
  pdfkeywords = {economics, econometrics, empirical industrial organization,
    applied microeconomics},
  pdftitle = {\name: Curriculum Vitae},
  pdfsubject = {Curriculum Vitae},
  pdfpagemode = UseNone
}

\geometry{
  body={6.5in, 9.0in},
  left=1.0in,
  top=1.0in
}

% Don't indent paragraphs.
\setlength\parindent{0em}

% Make lists without bullets and compact spacing
\renewenvironment{itemize}{
  \begin{list}{}{
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em}
      \setlength{\itemsep}{0.25em}
      \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
      \setlength{\parsep}{0.25em}
    }
}{
  \end{list}
}
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=0.25em}

% Print the month and year
\renewcommand{\today}{\ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May%
\or June\or July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi%
\space \number \year}

\begin{document}

% Place name at left and date at right
\titlefont{\name}

% Alternatively, print name centered and bold:
%\centerline{\titlefont{\name}}

% Date
\bigskip
\today

% Contact Information
\bigskip
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.495\textwidth}
  Department of Economics \\
  The Ohio State University \\
  410 Arps Hall \\
  1945 N High Street \\
  Columbus, Ohio 43210
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.495\textwidth}
  Phone: (614) 292-5588 \\
  Fax: (614) 292-3906 \\
  Office: 401 Arps Hall \\
  Email: \href{mailto:blevins.141@osu.edu}{blevins.141@osu.edu} \\
  Homepage: \href{http://jblevins.org/}{http://jblevins.org/}
\end{minipage}

\section*{Academic Positions}

\begin{itemize}
\item The Ohio State University, Department of Economics
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Associate Professor, 2017--present.
  \item Assistant Professor, 2010--2017.
  \end{itemize}
\item Yale Center for Customer Insights,
  Melville Blake '80 Visiting Summer Fellow,
  2012.
\item Duke University,
  Research and Teaching Assistant,
  2005--2010.
\end{itemize}

% \subsection*{Duke University, Department of Economics}
%
% \begin{itemize}
% \item Research Assistant, Jacob Vigdor, Summer 2005--Summer 2006.
% \item Teaching Assistant, Ph.D. Microeconomic Analysis, Thomas Nechyba, Fall 2005.
% \item Teaching Assistant, Ph.D. Game Theory, Curtis Taylor, Spring 2006.
% \item Instructor, Microeconomics Qualifier Camp, Summer 2006.
% \item Research Assistant, Han Hong, Fall 2006--Spring 2007.
% \item Research Assistant, Aprajit Mahajan and Alessandro Tarozzi,
%   October--November 2006, March--June 2007.
% \item Research Assistant, Shakeeb Khan and Christopher Timmins,
%   March--June 2007.
% \item Teaching Assistant, Ph.D. Econometrics II, Shakeeb Khan,
%   Spring 2007.
% \item Research Assistant, Peter Arcidiacono, Patrick Bayer,
%   and Paul Ellickson, Fall 2007--Spring 2009.
% \item Research Assistant, Shakeeb Khan, Fall 2009--Spring 2010.
% \item Research Assistant, Aprajit Mahajan, July--September 2009.
% \end{itemize}

% \subsection*{North Carolina State University, Department of Mathematics}
%
% \begin{itemize}
% \item Research Assistant, Moody Chu and Robert Funderlic,
%   Spring 2003--Fall 2004.
% \item Mathematics Tutor, Academic Support Program for Student Athletes,
%   Summer 2001.
% \end{itemize}

% \subsection*{Colorado School of Mines,
%   Department of Mathematical and Computer Sciences}
%
% \begin{itemize}
% \item Research Assistant, Willy Hereman, Summer 2002.
% \end{itemize}

\section*{Education}

\begin{itemize}
  \item Ph.D. Economics, Duke University, 2010.
    % Received May 16, 2010
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Dissertation Title: ``Essays in Industrial Organization and Econometrics''.
    \item Committee: Han Hong (co-chair), Shakeeb Khan (co-chair), Paul Ellickson, Andrew Sweeting.
    \item Institute on Computational Economics Fellow, University of Chicago, 2006.
    \end{itemize}
  \item M.A. Economics, Duke University, 2006.
    % Received May 14, 2006
  \item B.S. Applied Mathematics, \textit{Summa Cum Laude},
    North Carolina State University, 2004.
    % Received May 14, 2004
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Phi Beta Kappa, Zeta of North Carolina, 2003.
    \item Budapest Semesters in Mathematics, Fall 2002.
    \item NSF Research Experiences for Undergraduates, Colorado School of Mines, 2002.
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\section*{Research Interests}

Econometrics, Empirical Industrial Organization, Applied Microeconomics

\section*{Peer-Reviewed Publications}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Blevins, J.~R. and S.~Khan (2013).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/lnlls}{Local NLLS Estimation of Semiparametric Binary Choice Models}.
  \textit{Econometrics Journal} 16, 135--160.
\item Blevins, J.~R. and S.~Khan (2013).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/dfbr/}{Distribution-Free Estimation of Heteroskedastic Binary Response Models in Stata}.
  \textit{Stata Journal} 13, 588--602.
\item Blevins, J.~R. (2014).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/dcident}{Nonparametric Identification of Dynamic Decision Processes with Discrete and Continuous Choices}.
  \textit{Quantitative Economics} 5, 531--554.
\item Blevins, J.~R. (2015).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/seqgame}{Structural Estimation of Sequential Games of Complete Information}.
  \textit{Economic Inquiry} 53, 791--811.
\item Blevins, J.~R. (2015).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/cuberoot}{Non-Standard Rates of Convergence of Criterion-Function-Based Set Estimators for Binary Response Models}.
  \textit{Econometrics Journal} 18, 172--199.
\item Arcidiacono, P., P.~Bayer, J.~R. Blevins, P.~B. Ellickson (2016).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/abbe}{Estimation of Dynamic Discrete Choice Models in Continuous Time with an Application to Retail Competition}.
  \textit{Review of Economic Studies} 83, 889--931.
\item Blevins, J.~R. (2016).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/smcdmm}{Sequential Monte Carlo Methods for Estimating Dynamic Microeconomic Models}.
  \textit{Journal of Applied Econometrics} 31, 773--804.
\item Blevins, J.~R. (2017).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/sde}{Identifying Restrictions for Finite Parameter Continuous Time Models with Discrete Time Data}.
  \textit{Econometric Theory} 33, 739--754.
\item Blevins, J.~R., A. Khwaja, and N. Yang.
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/bky}{Firm Expansion, Size Spillovers and Market Dominance in Retail Chain Dynamics}.
  Forthcoming at \textit{Management Science}.
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Other Publications}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Blevins, J.~R. (2009).
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/generic-list}{A Generic Linked List Implementation in Fortran 95}.
  \textit{ACM Fortran Forum} 28(3), 2--7.
\end{enumerate}

\section*{Working Papers}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item Blevins, J.~R. and G.~T Senney.
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/dcs}{Dynamic Selection and Distributional Bounds on Search Costs in Dynamic Unit-Demand Models}.
  Revise and resubmit at \textit{Quantitative Economics}.
\item Blevins, J.~R., W. Shi., D.~R. Haurin, and S. Moulton.
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/ddc-hecm}{A Dynamic Discrete Choice Model of Reverse Mortgage Borrower Behavior}.
\item Blevins, J.~R.
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/ctgames}{Identification and Estimation of Continuous Time Dynamic Games}.
\item Blevins, J.~R.
  \href{http://jblevins.org/research/panel}{Partial Identification and Inference in Binary Choice and Duration Panel Data Models}.
\end{enumerate}

% \section*{Work in Progress}

% \begin{enumerate}[resume]
% \item Blevins, J.~R. and C.~Ma.
%     Learning by Doing in DRAM Production.
% \item Blevins, J.~R. and A. Khwaja.
%     Corporate Structure and Growth Strategies in the Retail Home Improvement Industry.
% \end{enumerate}

% \subsection*{Scientific Software}
%
% \begin{itemize}
% \item \href{http://jblevins.org/research/pdest}{PDESolutionTester},
%   A Mathematica program for the symbolic verification of exact solutions
%   of nonlinear partial differential equations,
%   with Jeff Heath and Willy Hereman (2002).
% \item \href{http://jblevins.org/research/dfbr}{DFBR},
%   A Stata program for distribution-free estimation of heteroskedastic
%   binary response models,
%   with Shakeeb Khan (2009).
% \end{itemize}

\section*{Grants}

\begin{itemize}
\item Moulton, S. (PI),
Seligman, J.~S., Haurin, D.~R., Loibl, C., Blevins, J.~R. (Co-PIs).
Aging in Place: Managing the Use of Reverse Mortgages to Enable Housing Stability,
2013--2016.
U.S. Department of Housing and Urban Development (HUD).
\$555,004.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Honors \& Awards}

\begin{itemize}
\item Summer Research Fellowship, Duke University, 2007, 2008.
\item Outstanding Teaching Assistant Award, Duke University, 2006.
\item Undergraduate Research Award, North Carolina State University, 2004.
% \item Omicron Delta Epsilon, International Economics Honor Society, 2004.
% \item Pi Mu Epsilon, National Mathematics Honor Society, 2003.
% \item Phi Kappa Phi, 2002.
% \item Golden Key International Honour Society, 2002.
% \item Dean's List, North Carolina State University, 2000--2004.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Invited Seminars}

\begin{description}[font=\mdseries]
\item[2017]
  Indiana University,
  University of Maryland,
  University of Texas at Austin.
\item[2016]
  Ohio State University (Glenn College of Public Affairs),
  University of Arizona.
\item[2015]
  University of British Columbia.
\item[2014]
  Columbia University,
  University of Iowa,
  University of Kentucky.
\item[2013]
  University of Chicago,
  Northwestern University,
  University of Michigan.
\item[2012]
  Yale University (School of Management),
  Washington University (Olin Business School),
  University of Virginia.
\item[2011]
  Pennsylvania State University,
  University of Toronto,
  University of Texas at Austin,
  Vanderbilt University,
  University of Rochester (Simon Graduate School of Business),
  Ohio State University (AEDE).
\item[2010]
  Ohio State University,
  University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign,
  University of Western Ontario,
  University of Pittsburgh.
\end{description}

\section*{Conference Presentations}

\begin{description}[font=\mdseries]
\item[2017]
  American Economic Association Annual Meeting (Chicago, discussant).
\item[2016]
  University of Calgary Empirical Microeconomics Workshop (Banff).
\item[2015]
  World Congress of the Econometric Society (Montr\'{e}al),
  Stata Conference (Columbus),
  Midwest Econometrics Group (St. Louis Fed).
\item[2014]
  University of Calgary Empirical Microeconomics Workshop (Banff),
  International Industrial Organization Conference (IIOC, Chicago, presenter and discussant),
  Midwest Economics Association (Evanston, IL, presenter and discussant).
\item[2013]
  Midwest Econometrics Group (Indiana University).
\item[2011]
  Midwest Econometrics Group (Chicago, Booth).
\item[2010]
  Midwest Econometrics Group (Washington University),
  Triangle Econometrics Conference,
  ERID Conference on Identification Issues in Economics (Duke).
\end{description}

% \begin{itemize}
% \item University of Maryland, Department of Economics, February 27, 2017. % ddc-hecm
% \item University of Arizona, Department of Economics, November 8, 2016. % ddc-hecm
% \item The Ohio State University, Glenn College of Public Affairs, September 19, 2016. % ddc-hecm
% \item University of British Columbia, Department of Economics, September 18, 2015.
% \item University of Iowa, Department of Economics, November 12, 2014. % ctgames
% \item Columbia University, Department of Economics, November 6, 2014. % ctgames
% \item University of Kentucky, Department of Economics, October 17, 2014. % abbe
% \item University of Chicago, Department of Economics, December 5, 2013. % abbe
% \item Northwestern University, Department of Economics, December 3, 2013. % ctgames
% \item University of Michigan, Department of Economics, March 29, 2013. % abbe
% \item University of Virginia, Department of Economics, October 2, 2012. % abbe
% \item Washington University, Olin Business School, September 13, 2012. % abbe
% \item Yale University, School of Management, August 13, 2012. % smcdmm
% \item Yale University, School of Management, July 24, 2012. % abbe
% \item University of Toronto, Department of Economics, December 2, 2011. % abbe
% \item Pennsylvania State University, Department of Economics, November 7, 2011. % abbe
% \item The Ohio State University, Department of Economics, November 1, 2011. % cuberoot
% \item Vanderbilt University, Department of Economics, September 15, 2011. % panel
% \item University of Rochester, Simon Graduate School of Business, May 6, 2011. % smcdmm
% \item The Ohio State University, Department of Agricultural, Environmental, and Development Economics, April 21, 2011. % smcdmm
% \item University of Texas at Austin, Department of Economics, April 4, 2011. % panel
% \item University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, Department of Economics, February 16, 2010. % panel
% \item University of Western Ontario, Department of Economics, January 26, 2010. % abbe
% \item The Ohio State University, Department of Economics, January 21, 2010. % abbe
% \item University of Pittsburgh, Department of Economics, January 15, 2010. % panel
% \end{itemize}

% \begin{itemize}
% \item University of Calgary Empirical Microeconomics Workshop,
%   Banff, Canada, September 21, 2016. % ddc-hecm
% \item 25th Annual Meeting of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis, October 9--10, 2015. % sde
% \item 11th World Congress of the Econometric Society,
%   Montreal, Canada, August 17--21, 2015. % ctgames
% \item 2015 Stata Conference, Columbus, OH, July 30--31, 2015. % dfbr
% \item University of Calgary Empirical Microeconomics Workshop,
%   Banff, Canada, September 20--21, 2014. % ctgames
% \item 12th Annual International Industrial Organization Conference (IIOC),
%   Chicago, IL, April 12, 2014. % ctgames, discussion
% \item Midwest Economics Association Annual Meeting,
%   Evanston, IL, March 22, 2014. % ctgames, discussion
% \item 23rd Annual Meeting of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   Indiana University, October 25--26, 2013. % ctgames
% \item 21st Annual Meeting of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   University of Chicago Booth School of Business, October 7, 2011. % dcident
% \item 20th Annual Meeting of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   Washington University, October 2, 2010. % panel
% \item Triangle Econometrics Conference,
%   Research Triangle Park, NC, December 4, 2009. % panel
% \item ERID Conference on Identification Issues in Economics,
%   Duke University, October 3, 2008. % smcdmm
% \end{itemize}

\section*{Peer Review}

Reviewer for
\textit{Econometrica} (3),
\textit{Econometric Reviews} (4),
\textit{Econometric Theory},
\textit{Economic Inquiry} (5),
\textit{International Economic Review},
\textit{Journal of Applied Econometrics} (3),
\textit{Journal of Business and Economic Statistics} (4),
\textit{Journal of Computational Finance},
\textit{Journal of Economic Literature},
\textit{Journal of Econometric Methods},
\textit{Journal of Econometrics} (12),
\textit{Marketing Science},
\textit{Review of Economic Studies} (2),
\textit{Review of Economics and Statistics} (2),
\textit{Scandinavian Journal of Statistics},
\textit{Pakistan Journal of Statistics},
\textit{Quantitative Economics},
Cambridge University Press,
National Science Foundation,
Polish National Science Centre (2).

\section*{Professional Activities}

\begin{itemize}
\item Departmental service:
  Advisory Committee to the Chair (2017--19),
  Faculty Recruiting Committee (2010--11, 2011--12, 2014--15, 2016--17),
  Graduate Studies Committee (2012--13),
  Graduate Program Review Committee (2013--14),
  Undergraduate Studies Committee (2014--15),
  Econometrics seminar organizer (Autumn 2016),
  G.S. Maddala Prize Committee (2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016).
\item Member, Econometric Society, 2006--Present.
\item Member, American Economic Association, 2010--Present.
\item Member, American Statistical Association, 2011--Present.
\end{itemize}

\section*{Advising}

\subsection*{Ph.D. Students, as Primary Advisor (Initial Placement in Parentheses)}

\begin{itemize}
\item \href{http://chaoma2014.weebly.com}{Chao Ma} (2015, Assistant Professor, Xiamen University, WISE, co-advisor with Donald Haurin)
\item \href{http://garrettsenney.weebly.com}{Garrett T. Senney} (2016, Financial Economist, Office of the Comptroller of the Currency)
\item \href{http://junqiushi-ren.weebly.com}{Junqiushi Ren} (2017, Assistant Professor, Southwestern University of Finance and Economics, RIEM) % Research Institute of Economics and Management
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Ph.D. Students, as Committee Member}

\begin{itemize}
\item Chih-Sheng Hsieh (2013, Assistant Professor, Chinese University of Hong Kong)
\item Chao Yang (2015, Assistant Professor, Shanghai University of Finance and Economics)
\item Xingbai Xu (2016, Assistant Professor, Xiamen University, WISE)
\item Xiang Hui (2016, Postdoctoral Researcher, MIT Sloan)
\item Wei Shi (2016, Assistant Professor, Jinan University Institute for Economic and Social Research)
\item Kai Yang (2016, Assistant Professor, Shanghai University of Finance and Economics)
\item Jongwook Park (2017, Economist, Bank of Korea)
\item Bosung Jang (2017, Economist, Bank of Korea)
\item Neslihan Sakarya (2017, Assistant Professor, University of Essex)
\item Tuo Liu (2017, Assistant Professor, Xiamen University, WISE)
\item Hyewon Kim (2018, expected)
\item Joseph Rossetti (2018, expected)
\item Jon Michel (2018, expected)
\item Hanbat Jeong (2018, expected)
\item Hongyu Chen (2019, expected)
\item Bo Wang (2019, expected)
% Seonghoon Kim; candidacy exam, 2011
% Fei Jin; candidacy exam, 2011
% Xi Qu; candidacy exam, 2012
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Undergraduate Honors Students}

\begin{itemize}
\item Erik Lauritzen (2011, co-advisor with Jennifer Suchland)
\end{itemize}

\section*{Teaching}

\subsection*{The Ohio State University}

\begin{itemize}
\item Topics in Microeconometrics (Ph.D.):
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ843f11/}{Fall 2011}, % 5 students, 5 quarter credit hours
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ8833f12/}{Fall 2012}, % 11 students, 3 semester credit hours
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ8833f14/}{Fall 2014}, % 12 students, 3 semester credit hours
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ8833f15/}{Fall 2015}, % 7 students, 3 semester credit hours
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ8833f16/}{Fall 2016}. % 9 students, 3 semester credit hours
\item Econometrics I (Ph.D.):
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ741s11/}{Spring 2011}. % 47 students, 5 quarter credit hours
\item Econometrics II:
  Spring 2012, % 60 students, 5 quarter credit hours
  Fall 2012, % 24 students, 3 semester credit hours
  Fall 2016, % 55 students, 3 semester credit hours
  Spring 2017. % 90 students, 3 semester credit hours
\item Introductory Econometrics:
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ444w11/}{Winter 2011}, % 57 students, 5 quarter credit hours
  Spring 2014, % 60 students, 3 semester credit hours
  Fall 2014, % 87 students, 3 semester credit hours
  Spring 2015. % 110 students, 3 semester credit hours
\item Econometrics seminar organizer:
  Fall 2016.
\end{itemize}

\subsection*{Duke University}

\begin{itemize}
\item Microeconomics Qualifier Camp (Ph.D.):
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/qualcamp06/}{Summer 2006}.
\item Econometrics II (Ph.D.):
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ342s07/}{Spring 2007}, teaching assistant for Shakeeb Khan.
\item Microeconomic Analysis II (Ph.D.):
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ302s06/}{Spring 2006}, teaching assistant for Curtis Taylor.
\item Microeconomic Analysis I (Ph.D.):
  \href{http://jblevins.org/courses/econ301f05/}{Fall 2005}, teaching assistant for Thomas Nechyba.
\end{itemize}


% \section*{Conference Participation}

% \begin{itemize}
% \item University of Calgary Empirical Microeconomics Workshop,
%   Banff, Canada, September 20--21, 2014.
% \item 12th Annual International Industrial Organization Conference (IIOC),
%   Chicago, IL, April 11-13, 2014.
% \item Midwest Economics Association Annual Meeting,
%   March 21--23, 2014.
% \item 23rd Annual Meeting of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   Indiana University, Department of Economics,
%   October 25--26, 2013.
% \item NBER/NSF/CEME Conference on the Econometrics of Dynamic Games,
%   New York University, Stern School of Business,
%   August 10--11, 2012.
% \item 2012 China India Insights Conference,
%   Yale University School of Management,
%   August 2--3, 2012.
% \item AEA/ASSA Annual Meetings,
%   Chicago, IL, January 5--8, 2012.
% \item 2011 Meetings of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   University of Chicago Booth School of Business,
%   October 6-7, 2011.
% \item North American Summer Meetings of the Econometric Society,
%   Washington University,
%   June 9--12, 2011.
% \item AEA/ASSA Annual Meetings,
%   Denver, CO, January 6--10, 2011.
% \item 20th Annual Meetings of the Midwest Econometrics Group,
%   Washington University,
%   October 1--2, 2010.
% \item AEA/ASSA Annual Meetings,
%   Atlanta, GA, January 3--5, 2010.
% \item Triangle Econometrics Conference,
%   Research Triangle Park, NC,
%   December 4, 2009.
% \item Cowles Foundation Conference, Applications of Structural Microeconomics,
%   Yale University,
%   June 24--25, 2009.
% \item ERID Conference on Identification,
%   Duke University,
%   October 3--4, 2008.
% \item North American Summer Meetings of the Econometric Society,
%   Duke University,
%   June 21--24, 2007.
% \item Institute on Computational Economics,
%   Argonne National Laboratory,
%   July 17--21, 2006.
% \item SIAM Conference on Applied Linear Algebra,
%   The College of William \& Mary,
%   July 15--19, 2003.
% \end{itemize}

\section*{Miscellaneous}

\begin{itemize}
\item Google Open Source Programs Office sponsorship of Markdown Mode for Emacs, June 2015, \$250.
\item \textit{Programming Languages:} Fortran, Matlab, \LaTeX, Emacs Lisp, Perl, Python, Stata, Mata, C, C++, SQL.
\item \textit{Security Clearance:} Special Sworn Status, U.S. Census Bureau.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

It returned with the following errors,

```
"fontspec error: "font-not-found" The font "Garamond Premier Pro" cannot be found. For immediate help type H <return>.
 \setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}"
```

Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the CV is public?

Comment: If you don't have `Garamond Premier Pro` you will have to use another font.

Comment: @egreg The CV (+TeX template) seems to be taken from http://jblevins.org/projects/cv-template/.

Comment: Yes, its from Blevins.

Comment: but you have to buy the font or xetex will not find it.